# UICollectionView showing images related to the selected cell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

I have a CollectionView and what I want to do is when someone taps on one cell, this cell takes you a another view where it shows you all images related to the selected cell. **My problem is that I am having trouble evaluating which one of all my cells is the selected cell, so I can assign in the next view all images related to the selected cell. I get an error with my the approach I am using...**

[image]

Comment: indexPath has a "row" property so indexPath.row == 0 indexPath.row == 1 etc

Comment: i'm sorry this is a collection view so it's indexPath.item i think

Comment: [indexPathsForSelectedItems](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/UICollectionView) [NSIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/).

Comment: I tried that, however, when I write indexPath.item I get an error. Xcode autocomplete do not show me the ITEM property as an option :S

Comment: ah, so indexPath is an optional? you should read up on optionals they are usually returned by api calls from objective - c, but to quickly fix your issue you could do indexPath!.item, but i highly recommend reading up on them.

Comment: Check the return type of the method you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let route = segue.destinationViewController as DetailCollectionViewController

if let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()?.first as? NSIndexPath {
        switch indexPath.item {
        case 0:
                route.passedArray = detailCollection1
        case 1:
                route.passedArray = detailCollection2
        default:
                break
        }
}

/* for multiple selection

// iterate over the indexPathsForSelectedItems if it is not nil
for indexPath in collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems() as [NSIndexPath] {
    // do your wok
}

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

indexPath.row is giving you the first cell. If you have more sections, use first indexPath.section to choose in what section you are selecting the cell.